# document.getelementbyid not working inside loop/if

Tags: c#, browser

My problem is simple yet i cannot figure out why it's not working inside of if/loop. Here are some examples:

Working one:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("value", "something");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "something");
}
```

Non working one:

```
if (webBrowser1.IsBusy == false)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("value", "something");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "something");
}
```

No matter what the "if" statement is, it's not working. Also tried with "for", also tried to get it out of the loop of "for", i still get this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Use a debugger and find out which object is `null`. Is it `webBrowser1`? Or `webBrowser1.Document`? Or the result of `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(…)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here because of the limited information.

I think you are trying to modify the page right after setting the `Url` property. The webpage will not yet be loaded then so the controls you are getting are not available yet.

Try adding the code to the `DocumentCompleted` event of the `WebBrowser`. This event will be triggered right after the document is fully loaded and the elements will be available then.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  var loginControl = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login");
  var passwordControl = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password");

  if (loginControl != null)
    loginControl.SetAttribute("value", "something");

  if (passwordControl != null)
    passwordControl.SetAttribute("value", "something");
}
```

more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx

**Update**

Your assumption about `IsBusy` is not completely correct. It starts out `false` when nothing is loaded. settings the `Url` property will not immediately set it to `true`.

For an alternative you requested you could use the `ReadyState` property that will have the value of `WebBrowserReadyState.Complete` when loading is done. you could use the following example. Although i personally don't like it as there is the risk of endless loop when the page can't load for some reason. I would advise to use the `DocumentCompleted` if possible and i modified that example to correctly handle non-login pages as well.

```
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
  Thread.Sleep(0);
  Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: Actually i was thinking the same but shouldnt "if (webBrowser1.IsBusy == false)" check if the webbrowser is loading. i am aware of the "webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted" but it's not very usable in my case. So if you know any other method to check if the browser is loading(inside a loop or if) that would be great :)

Comment: I added some info and an alternative to my answer. Hope this will help you.